# Can I direct traffic on a subdomain to a Virtual Box running under Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have a Virtual Box running Windows under Ubuntu host and the VM has a small IIS web application that I need to access. 
I know I can remote to the VM using various tools, but it would be much more convenient if I could expose the VM through my router out to public so that I can access the application on VM using just a URL (subdomain).

Currently I've created a subdomain that points to my home router IP address. I obtained the IP using ("what is my IP" Google search).

But this hits the router and stops there. I need to somehow tell the router that all incoming HTTPS requests from outside to be forwarded to my VM. In the same time I don't want to block the internet access on all the devices in the home, so probably I'd need to filter the HTTP requests to forward to VM to be just the ones coming from that subdomain url or that hit the HTTP. I could also create a weird port name like 1234 that would hit the VM but translate somehow to HTTPS as that is what the VM has.

I've never done this before so any suggestion is highly appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM is not known by the router as its network is tunneled through the host. You have to open the port from your router to your host system, and in the Virtualbox settings of your VM -> Network -> Port Forwarding forward that port to the VM.

If you should do that is another question, opening ports to the internet is always a risk, especially when you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I believe I've done that, but it still doesn't work, so maybe I'm missing something. There are 3 actors here: router, the host computer and the VM. Subdomain points to the router IP (I've checked that with a ping and it shows the router IP). Then the host has a port forwarding (using NAT) to the VM, but I believe the missing link is how does the router forward the request to the host computer, that I don't know and probably is what I'm missing... Right now I'm getting "unable to connect" message

Comment: sure, that is what I say: *"You have to open the port from your router to your host system"*. How to do that is not an Ubuntu question and usually very easy to find when you search for it including your routers brand name.

Comment: yes, that was it. all I was missing was "open the port" so port forwarding on router fixed the issue. Thank you pLumo!

Comment: Great. Be careful with that setup. Close the port when you don't need it anymore. Consider using a software firewall on the host to control the port.